# Cambiar el background de un body con php y javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo que cambiar la imagen del background  que asigné por css a un body dependiendo de la validación que haga con un if en php, seria algo asi:

```
 if(!empty($userData)){
        echo "<script language='javascript'>"; 
        echo "document.body.style.backgroundImage='none'";
        //echo "$('.cuerpo').css('background-image', 'none');"; 
        echo "</script>";  

    }else{
        echo "no se cambia el background";
    }
```

No encuentro como hacerlo, la idea es que el php valide un valir y si este es verdadero haga varias cosas entre otras quitarle el background a un body.

Comment: Usas jquery en tu plataforma o cms?

Comment: Te recomiendo tener lo más separado posible tu JS y tu PHP por razones de legibilidad y mantenimiento.

Podrías hacer una petición por ajax a la operación PHP que te da el resultado $userdata que usas, y si retorna exitosamente, entonces cambias los estilos con JS. Si te interesa cómo, pongo un ejemplo como respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo hacer algo asi:

```
if ( !empty($userData) ) {
    $bgNone = "<style type='text/css'>body {background-image:'none'}</style>";
    echo $bgNone;
}else{
   echo "no se cambia el background";
}
```